# how to access a file that is located on a different hard drive from within a python script

Tags: python, filesystem

And another related question: how to access a file via network from within a python script; the Network is a samba share.

I tried different things, but can't figure it out. I keep getting: **No such file or directory**

I am running the script like this:

```
$ /usr/bin/python3 "/home/nathaniel/Documents/my first python script.py"
```

This is my mount:

```
/media/nathaniel/ssd/
```

This is my file:

```
/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/SD/1.avi
```

I have been trying different things, but nothing works.

This is a simplified version of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
import tempfile
sourcedir = "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/SD"
diroutput = "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/HD"
sourceExt = "avi"
def getFileNames():
    global filenamefirst 
    filenamefirst = int(input("enter file name NUMBER to start with: "))
    global filenamelast 
filenamelast = int(input("enter NUMBER of last file to process: "))
def main():
    import os
    import os.path
    getFileNames()
    for x in range(filenamefirst, filenamelast+1):
        if os.path.exists(diroutput + "/" + str(x) + ".mp4"):
            os.remove(diroutput + "/" + str(x) + ".mp4")
        from subprocess import check_output
        check_output("ffmpeg -i \"" + sourcedir + "/" + str(x) + "." + sourceExt + "\" -c:v libx264 -b:v 18M -c:a aac \"" + diroutput + "/" + str(x) + ".mp4\"")
        print("^======= finished file " + str(x) + "." + sourceExt)
    print("end")

main()
```

the error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/SD/1.avi" -c:v libx264 -b:v 50M -c:a aac "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/HD/1.mp4"': 'ffmpeg -i "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/SD/1.avi" -c:v libx264 -b:v 50M -c:a aac "/media/nathaniel/ssd/test/HD/1.mp4"'
```

Comment: @dessert I added a simplified version of the script.

Comment: Does it work if the file is on the same drive? Have you tested that?

Comment: @jpezz I am getting the same error. `No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -i "/home/nathaniel/Documents/scripts/test/SD/1.avi" -c:v libx264 -b:v 50M -c:a aac "/home/nathaniel/Documents/scripts/test/HD/1.mp4"':`

Comment: When you do `ls /home/nathaniel/Documents/scripts/test/SD/1.avi` on the command line it does show up, right?  Because that script is running against a differet file than you mentioned trying to access...

Comment: I just got it to work. It needed `check_output(command, shell=True)` the `shell=True` was somehow required (not with Windows 10)

Comment: @ThomasWard yes - `ls /home/nathaniel/Documents/scripts/test/SD/1.avi` is showing up. (Sorry, - I since moved it to my local drive) I will still have to get it working via network and other drive.

Comment: Please add an answer explaining how you got it to work below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that any of these worked over a network:

```
"\\\\192.168.1.1\\c\\my.file"

"\\\\computername\\c\\my.file"
```

or locally:

```
"d:\\foldername\\my.file"`
```

or:

```
r"d:\foldername\my.file"
```